# Microsoft Likes the False value better?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, nullable, boolean-logic

Im reading Jon Skeet book. (#4)

but one thing (among others) caught my eye :

topic :  bool?

he wrote in a table that :(X,Y are bool?)

```
X      |    Y     |   X & Y
---------------------------
true        null       null
```

ok fine... so the null is the one who decides.
the bool operand here looses.

```
X      |    Y     |   X & Y
---------------------------
false      null       false
```

**why ?**
why the bool operand here is being taking into account while in the previous sample it was the null who decided about the result ...?

It seems that true and false has friends in different places....:)

Comment: See the truth tables for [three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). I presume that is likely the rationale but don't know for certain.

Comment: This is not the ["false operator"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6292hy1k.aspx), which is a user-defined conversion.

Comment: It's the opposite for `||`: `null || true == true`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pronounce *null* as *unknown*.

```
true  & unknown => unknown
false & unknown => false       because the second operand does not matter.
```

And of course there is the mirror table for OR :

```
true  | unknown => true        because the second operand does not matter. 
false | unknown => unknown
```

And it holds for `&&` and `||` as well.

Comment: I thought that when working with bitwise operators, both operands matter?

Comment: @haiyyu - both operands are evaluated, but `false & x` is always false, whether `x` is true, false or unknown.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it was designed that way is to be consistent with [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), as implemented in numerous other platforms, including SQL. In Kleene logic (on which three-valued logic is based), `TRUE AND UNKNOWN` gives `UNKNOWN`, while `FALSE AND UNKNOWN` gives `FALSE`.

You may refer to the section titled “[The bool? type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx#sectionToggle6)” within [Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) for an explanation and enumeration of the results in C#.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, it is...

> To ensure that the results produced by the & and | operators are consistent with the three-valued Boolean type in SQL

[The truth table for bitwise operations on nullable booleans can be found on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are now dealing with [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Kleene_logic).

- for an AND operator (be it & or &&) the expression result can be determined at the first match for FALSE.
- for an OR operator (be it | or ||) the expression result can be determined at the first match for TRUE.
- for any boolean operation having a left most operand of NULL will return NULL.

So the tables you list are incomplete: you need more entries to see what happens when, as there are 8 possible input combinations (nine if you count the `null operator null` combination).

AND:

```
X      |    Y     |   X & Y
---------------------------
true       null        null
null       true        null
false      null       false
null       false       null

true       false      false
true       true        true
false      true       false
false      false      false
```

OR:

```
X      |    Y     |   X | Y
---------------------------
true       null        true
null       true        null
false      null        null
null       false       null

true       false       true
true       true        true
false      true        true
false      false      false
```

Using your `friends` analogy, you could say that, for three-valued logic, AND favours FALSE and NULL as outcome whereas OR favours TRUE and NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The && and || operators are both evaluated according to  [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means once a complex expression has been determined to be false, the remaining expressions will not be checked. Since false value in second expression is enough to determine the result of logical AND, result is determined as false directly.

Comment: Note that short `circuit evaluation` (for && and ||) does not matter for the results of the expressions. Short circuit evaluation just stops evaluating sub-expressions when the result can be determined, whereas normal evaluation always evaluates all sub-expressions regardless if their results are still needed.