# In most SQL implementations, as opposed to standard programming languages, why doesn't x != null return true?

Tags: sql, null

Let's suppose that `x` is some variable that has any value other than `null`, say 4, as an example. What should the following expression return?

```
x != null
```

In just about every programming language I have ever worked with (C#, Javascript, PHP, Python), this expression, or an equivalent expression in that language, evaluates to `true`.

SQL implementations, on the other hand, all seem to handle this quite differently. If one or both operands of the inequality operator are `NULL`, either `NULL` or `False` will be returned. This is basically the opposite of the behavior that most programming languages use, and it is *extremely* unintuitive to me.

Why is the behavior in SQL like this? What is it about relationaly database logic that makes `null` behave so much differently than it does in general purpose programming?

Comment: does x!= null work in many SQL implementations? I have always used x is not null.

Comment: Because `NULL` is unknown. It might be 4. This is definitely a dupe.

Comment: One way I heard it explained is that "NULL is a state of being, not a value".

Comment: @MartinSmith Then why wouldn't it be the same way in other programming languages?

Comment: @PeterOlson - I think it is with nullable types in `C#`

Comment: @MartinSmith No it isn't. `int? x = 3; x != null` returns `true`

Comment: @PeterOlson: Probably you will get much more information from [the Wikipedia entry on NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Controversy) than here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @PeterOlson - Yep I remembered that wrong. I recalled seeing a question about them for which the answer was to do with 3 valued logic recently - which I found here but [not really relevant to what you are asking though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241314/microsoft-likes-the-false-value-better)

Comment: my guess - result of a historical decision and then just maintaining backward compatibility

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The null in most programming languages is considered "known", while NULL in SQL is considered "unknown".

- So `X == null` compares X with a known value and the result is known (true or false).
- But `X = NULL` compares X with an unknown value and the result is unknown (i.e. NULL, again). As a consequence, we need a special operator `IS [NOT] NULL` to test for it.

I'm guessing at least part of the motivation for such NULLs would be the behavior of foreign keys. When a child endpoint of a foreign key is NULL, it shouldn't match any parent, even if the parent is NULL (which is possible if parent is UNIQUE instead of primary key). Unfortunately, this brings many more [gotchas](http://thoughts.j-davis.com/2009/08/02/what-is-the-deal-with-nulls/) than it solves and I personally think SQL should have gone the route of the "known" null and avoided this monkey business altogether.

Even E. F. Codd, inventor or relational model, later indicated that the traditional NULL is not optimal. But for historical reasons, we are pretty much stuck with it.

Answer (score 6):

the reason is that the concept of equality doesn't apply to null. it's not logically true to say that this null does or does not equal this other null.

so, that's all fine for a theoretical reason, but for the sake of convenience, why does sql not allow your to say (x != null)?

well, the reason is because sometimes you want to handle nulls differently.
if I say (columnA = columnB) for example, should that return true if both columns are null? 
if I say (columnA != columnB) - should it give the same result when column A is "a" and column B is null, and when column A is "a" and column B is "b"?

the people who made sql decided that distinction was important and so they wrote it to treat the 2 cases differently.

the wikipedia page on this has a pretty decent writeup - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29

Comment: Why is this special to databases? Why didn't people do the same comparison behavior with nullable types in standard programming languages?

Comment: well, if I was to guess... SQL is more rooted in the concepts of functional style programming. standard programming languages are generally imperative. in SQL you're essentially describing the problem and letting your db server figure out how to solve the problem. from imperative side you're normally telling the program how to solve your problem step by step. typically people who are into functional logic care more deeply about the underlying meaning of functional statements than an imperative approach where we assume we can tell it how to fix the problem.

Comment: in short: from a functional perspective, its more important to be able to accurately describe your problem.

Comment: Meh, I don't see how the paradigm difference really affects this comparison problem. In a functional language like F#, for example, `Some(x) <> None` returns `True`

Comment: it was a design decision. the people behind F# came to a different decision. remember that f# is built on top of the .net clr and so is influenced by that and the years of experience dealing with sql and other functional approaches and get to pick and choose what to use. sql was developed a long time ago and can't really change course on something so fundamental now.

Answer (score 1):

well in sql engines you usually don't use the "=" operator but "IS", which then makes it more intuitive.

```
SELECT 4 IS NULL FROM dual;
> 0


SELECT 4 IS NOT NULL FROM dual;
> 1
```

NULL doesn't stand for null pointer, it's just not the same concept at all. 
sql NULL is a *I don't know the value* flag, it's not a "there's no pointer" flag. You just should not compare them, they shouldn't be used the same way. This is pretty unintuitive you're right, they should have named it differently.

Comment: I am aware that the IS (NOT) NULL operator exists, this doesn't really answer my question; I'm asking about why `!=` works the way it does, not about ways to work around its strange behavior

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `NULL` means "an unknown value".

If you say x != NULL you are saying "is the value of x unequal to an unknown value". Well, since we don't know what unknown value is, we don't know if x is equal to it or not. So the answer is "I don't know".

Similarly:

```
x = NULL OR 1=2    -- Unknown. 1=2 is not true, but we don't know about x=NULL
x = NULL OR 1=1    -- True. We know that at least 1=1 is true, so the OR is fulfulled regardless.
x = NULL AND 1=1   -- Unknown. We want them both to be true to fulful the AND
x = NULL AND 1=2   -- False. We know 1=2 is false, so the AND is not fulfilled regardless.
```

Also

```
-- Neither statement will select rows where x is null
select x from T where x = 1
select x from T where x != 1
```

The only way to check a null is to specificaly ask "is it true that we don't know what the value of x is". That has a yes or no answer, and uses the `IS` keyword.

If you just want nulls to be treated as zero, or another value, you can use the `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` function.

```
COALESCE(NULL, 1)  -- 1
COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 1) -- Also 1
COALESCE(x, y, z, 0) -- x, unless it is null, then y, unless it is null, then z, unless it is null in which case 0.
```

Comment: In SQL, null does *not* truly represent an unknown value. If it did then X=X would properly evaluate to TRUE (in maths, logic and reality an unknown value is certainly equal to itself!) The SQL standard doesn't in fact define the meaning of null, it simply defines its syntax and (strange, inconsistent, un-mathematical) behaviour. The idea that null somehow "means" unknown is just an inaccurate and often dangerous assumption made by some SQL practitioners.

Comment: Questioner was looking for a way to understand NULL, not the SQL standard definition.

Comment: "in maths, logic and reality an unknown value is certainly equal to itself". No. One unknown value is not neccessarily equal to another unknown value. I don't know Joel Spolsky's date of birth nor do I know Raymond Chen's date of birth. That doesn't mean they are the same.

Comment: Different problem. Joel Spolsky's date of birth is exactly equal to Joel Spolsky's date of birth. But if Joel Spolsky's date of birth in the database is NULL then it is not equal to itself. That is one example (among many others) of why NULL does not accurately represent the "unknown" case. Practically and logically speaking it's a misconception to think that null always means unknown.